# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'am trying to use AuthService into UsersService and UsersService into AuthService, so this is called "circular dependency". The issue is that "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (UserModel, JwtService, ?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [2] is available in the AuthModule context."

UsersModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: User.name, schema: UserSchema
      }
    ]),
    forwardRef(() => AuthModule),
  ],
  controllers: [UsersController],
  providers: [UsersService], 
  exports: [UsersService]
}) 
export class UsersModule {}enter code here
```

AuthModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{name: User.name, schema: UserSchema}]),
    JwtModule.register({ secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET }),
    forwardRef(() => UsersModule),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService, JwtStrategy],
  exports: [AuthService, JwtModule]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

UsersService (works fine):

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
      @InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<UserDocument>,
      private jwtService: JwtService,
      private authService: AuthService
    ) {}
...
```

AuthService (where error occurs):

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
      @InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<UserDocument>, 
      private jwtService: JwtService,
      private userService: UsersService,
    ) {}
...
```

Comment: have you tried this approach: https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency#forward-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've  resolved the circular dependency between the modules, but not between the services. Each side of the service needs `@Inject(forwardRef(() => InjectedClass))`. So your `AuthService` would use `@Inject(forwardRef(() => UserService))`

Comment: Although that might work, it's a very bad pattern. Find other patterns where you don't need two services to depend on each other.

Comment: I don't disagree with you that circular dependencies should be avoided when possible. Just stating what would need to happen without a redesign to get the error gone

Answer (score 0):

Circular dependencies are bad and trying to get around them using things like `forwardRef` mentioned in the other answer is not good practice.

Look into other patterns for inter-service communication. Events for example: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/events